# Finite state machine question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-state-machine

How do I find a regular expression for this language, and how do I define a finite state machine that recognizes words in the language (input alphabet, states, start state, state transition table, and accept states). Including a state digraph for the FSM for this language,

L: For alphabet $\{0,1\}$, all strings of length 3 or less that have more $0$'s than $1$'s

Comment: I would do a visual representation of the FSM with nodes / edges.  The set-builder definition of FSM seems dry and hard-to-interpret.  Always go visual / graphical when there's the opportunity!!

Answer (score 0):

You state machine will need to *count*. In general, state machines cannot count *arbitrarily* far, since they only have finitely many states, but they can count up to some maximum. In your case, you'll want to keep track of the number of $0$s and $1s$ until the sum of both counts exceeds three. Once it does that, you switch to an "overflowed" state, from which you never switch again, and which *isn't* an acceptance state.

If $(a,b)$ says you've so far seen $0$ $a$-times and $1$ $b$-times, and $\infty$ is the overflow state, you'll need the states $$
  \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(0,3),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0),\infty\}
$$
It shoud be easy to describe the transitions between those states - what, for example happens if you're in state $(1,2)$ and the next input is a $1$? It should also be easy to find the acceptance states - just compare the counters for $0$ and $1$ to the condition stated in your question.